# Server doesn't detect second client connecting

Tags: java, tcp, udp, client-server

The problem i have is that when i open a second client, the server doesn't seem to detect that a second client was opened. With the first time the client being opened it works fine and the server detects that a client has been connected.

Server:

```
public class Server {

Socket previousSocket = null;

private static int port = 9001;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("[SERVER] Server successfully launched on port: " + port);
    
    DatagramSocket UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket(9002);
    
    Socket previousSocket = null;
    while (true) {
        Socket newSocket = serverSocket.accept();

       System.out.println("new client connected");
        
        
        if (previousSocket == null) { 
            previousSocket = newSocket;
            
            System.out.println("1 st client");
            
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("2 nd client");
            previousSocket = null;
        }
       
       
        byte[] data = new byte[500];
        DatagramPacket received = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        
        while(true) {
            UDPSocket.receive(received);
            
            String receivedData = new String(received.getData());
            
            System.out.println(receivedData);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client:

```
public ChatClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9001);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    DatagramSocket UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String message = scanner.nextLine();
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
                
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, ip, 9002);
        UDPSocket.send(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner `while(true)` which calls `UDPSocket.receive(received);` never exits so the `serverSocket.accept();` in the outer loop is only called once. Though why do you have a ServerSocket on port 9001 in the first place when you are apparently only using port 9002 for sending and receiving data?

Answer (score 0):

The following loop will never end, that's the reason for your problem

```
        while(true) {
            UDPSocket.receive(received);
            
            String receivedData = new String(received.getData());
            
            System.out.println(receivedData);
        }
```